# Invalid Input Syntax for type Numeric -Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Can someone help me in writing the code and correcting this column logic? Looks like it is having Nulls when it is trying to convert to Numeric.

```sql
ST_DistanceSphere(
  ST_Point(act_coord.longitude,act_coord.latitude),
  ST_Point(
    str.physical_logitude::numeric(12,8),
    str.physical_lattitude::numeric(12,8)
  )
) / 1609.34
```

Thanks,
Am

I get the error and trying to write cast and coalesce and still see errors. Need help.

Comment: What is the _exact_ error you are receiving? What is the contents of `ct_coord` and `str`?

Comment: error:  Invalid input syntax for type numeric
  code:      8001
  context:   value: ""
  query:     33003820
  location:  cg_util.cpp:630
  process:   query0_126_33003820 [pid=15419]

Comment: Those are the tables. Dimensions ... Stores and the Activity Coordinates table.

Comment: they have latitude longitude info in the tables...

Comment: It appears that the error is saying there was an **empty string** (`""`) provided for one of those inputs. You might want to write a query that shows the _actual_ value of those values.